# At a time the panel color is changing only once after cloning the main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i'm trying to clone a `<div class="main"` and i need to change the color of this parent `div`.but at a time its changing only once `(only first panel)` after the cloning. Also cloning repeating multiple time on a button click while i need to clone it only once on every button click. Can someone help me to solve this?

Here is the code link: https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/k69pxad9/

```
<div class="body">
<div class="main">
<div class="inner">
<div class="content">
This is a test content
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="ChangeColor">
Change color
</button>
</div>

<Button type="button" class="clickButton">
Click on button
</Button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  padding-left:15px;
}
.inner {
  padding:15px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.clickButton').click(function(){
$('.main').clone().appendTo('.body');
});

$('.ChangeColor').click(function(){
$(this).parent('.main').css({backgroundColor: 'green'});
});

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2xaetwfp/

Answer (score 2):

Use delegate click event for dynamically created element please find below sample for you case.

I would recommend to use `.on` below is a signature of `.on` function

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );

$("body").on("click", "#YOUR_DYNAMICALLY_CREATED_ELEMENT", function(event){
    //Do Some stuff
});


// Your case it would be like below
$(document).on('click','.ChangeColor',function(){
    $(this).parent('.main').css({backgroundColor: 'green'});
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k69pxad9/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickButton').click(function(){
  $('.main').clone().appendTo('.body');
  $('.ChangeColor').click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".main").css({backgroundColor: 'green'});
  });
});
```

You try to add an event, before the Node is created.

Answer (score 0):

Add with `eq(0)`.Its clone only the one main element .And change the `ChangeColor` click function with [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlwZip9OzUAhUBuI8KHS27BmQQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w) .Because dynamically append element not working normal click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.clickButton').click(function() {
    $('.main').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.body');
  });

  $(document).on('click','.ChangeColor',function() {
    $(this).parent('.main').css({
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.inner {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="content">
        This is a test content
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="ChangeColor">
Change color
</button>
  </div>

  <Button type="button" class="clickButton">
Click on button
</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating your `.main` element dynamically, the javascript code you used will not work(since those elements are not yet created) & you need to use "event delegation" method to make it work.

```
$('.body').on('click', '.ChangeColor', function() {
  $(this).parent('.main').css({backgroundColor: 'green'});
});
```

**Explanation**:

Instead of binding the "click" event handler directly to the dynamically creating element(`.ChangeColor`), you can instead bind it to a parent element(`.body` or `<body>` or `document`) & **watch for a change/addition of new child elements**.

> Read more about delegation from [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the elements created by `.clone()` don’t bind handlers.

Use

```
$('.body').on('click', '.clickButton', function(){
    $('.main').clone().appendTo('.body');
});
```

to resolve it